# Google Analytics Traffic Sources issue with mobile traffic redirected to m. site

Tags: seo, google-analytics, http-redirect

A big chunk of my traffic is mobile. My server identifies this traffic by regex on the user agent and redirects (301) from www.mydomain.com to m.mydomain.com

My site has different sources I want to get insights on (ads, Facebook, referrer sites etc)

In the traffic sources report in Google Analytics  I see a big chunk of visits originate from  mydomain.com. That chunk size is similar to my mobile traffic, though a little lower.

Does it make sense that the traffic source issue is related to mobile?

If so:

- Is there a way to overcome this and have Google Analytics report the true traffic origin?

One option I saw was faking a Google campaign by having the server add fake parameters to the query. This way I can use Google Analytics advertising-related reports to track origin.

I'm looking for something more straightforward if possible.

Will HTTP 302 work better?

- Why would the traffic source chunk be smaller than the mobile chunk?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://www.lanevance.com/web/web-development/tracking-301-redirects-with-google-analytics/

This works for google but should work for other trackers too.